# Expected number of attempts to observe a pattern VS Probability of getting a pattern in n attempts

Tags: probability, combinations, monte-carlo

This question is more about general intuition, than formal mathematics.

Let's consider the fair coin toss (p=0.5, q=0.5) and the pattern of getting 3 heads in a row.

- **Expected number of attempts to observe a pattern** is given by (according to [Quora - What is the expected number of coin flips until ...](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-expected-number-of-coin-flips-until-you-get-3-heads-in-a-row)):

$$\mu= \frac{p^{-n}-1}{1-p} = 14$$

(There is several other ways to solve this problem all leading to the same result).

- **Probability of getting a pattern in n attempts** is given by (according to [Probability of streaks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383704/probability-of-streaks)):

$$
P(n,k) = p^k \sum _{t=0}^{\frac{n-k}{k+1}} \binom{n-k (t+1)}{t} \left(-q p^k\right)^t-\sum _{t=1}^{\frac{n}{k+1}} \binom{n-k t}{t} \left(-q p^k\right)^t
$$

from what we get:

P(14,3) = 0.6479 The probability to get 3 heads in a row after 14 attempts.

P(10,3) = 0.5078 The probability to get 3 heads in a row after 10 attempts.

The [Matlab Code](http://textuploader.com/djxyr) of a Monte-Carlo simulation shows the same results, and the distribution of results is plotted here:

[image: Probability of getting 3 heads in a row according to the number of attempts]

**My Question is:**

Can you help me get the intuition why:

- The expected number of attempts, to get 3 heads in a row (in this case 14)

is different than

- The number of attempts necessary, for the probability to get 3 heads in a row, to reach 0.5 (in this case 10)

Comment: The intuition is that the two are different because  the probability distribution is not symmetrical around the mean

Comment: Thank you. You are right. The mean of this distribution is 14 but the median is 10. So, when asked how many attempts would I need in order to accept to play this game (with an unlimited possibility of replay), I should answer 11, not 15, right?

Comment: Let's say entering the game is free. If you draw 3 heads in a row, you **earn 1$**. If you don't, you have to **pay $1**. You have a given N number of attempts. What would be the lowest ***N*** for wich you would accept to play if you can replay the game an infinite amount of times (hence you are risk-neutral). My answer would actually be ***N=10***, since if I can play 1000 times with 10 attempts, I will lose on average 492 times and win 508 times making a $16 profit.

Comment: You are correct, since the probability of a win, given $10$ attempts, $>0.5$.